# How to replace string in multiple files in the folder?

Tags: python-2.7

I m trying to read two files and replace content of one file with content of other file in files present in folder which also has sub directories.
But its tell sub process not defined.
 i'm new to python and shell script can anybody help me with this please?

```
import os
import sys
import os.path

f = open ( "file1.txt",'r')
g = open ( "file2.txt",'r')
text1=f.readlines()
text2=g.readlines()

i = 0;
for line in text1:
    l = line.replace("\r\n", "")
    t = text2[i].replace("\r\n", "")
    args = "find . -name *.tml"
    Path = subprocess.Popen( args , shell=True )
    os.system("  sed -r -i 's/" + l + "/" + t + "/g' " + Path)
    i = i + 1;
```

Comment: So far what this script does is assumes the two files have the same number of lines (or that the second is at least longer than the first). For each line it spawns a subprocess doing the same find command each time, but does nothing with its result. Then spawns another subprocess using os.system which does a sed command to which I am not clear of the outcome.

Comment: @jdi with sed command m trying to replace what ever content we have in file1 with content of file2 (line be line) in all the  files present in path.

Comment: @jdi m new to python to not sure where m going wrong..if you can help me out

Comment: Did my best to give a verbose answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

To specifically address your actual error, you need to import the subprocess module as you are making use of it (oddly) in your code:

```
import subprocess
```

After that, you will find more problems. I will try and keep it as simple as possible with my suggestions. Code first, then I will break it down. Keep in mind, there are more robust ways to accomplish this task. But I am doing my best to keep in mind your experience level and making it make your current approach as closely as possible.

```
import subprocess
import sys

# 1
results = subprocess.Popen("find . -name '*.tml'", 
                            shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

if results.wait() != 0:
    print "error trying to find tml files"
    sys.exit(1)

# 2
tml_files = []
for tml in results.stdout:
    tml_files.append(tml.strip())

if not tml_files:
    print "no tml files found"
    sys.exit(0)

tml_string = " ".join(tml_files)

# 3
with open ("file1.txt") as f, open("file2.txt") as g:
    while True:
# 4
        f_line = f.readline()
        if not f_line:
            break

        g_line = g.readline()
        if not g_line:
            break

        f_line = f_line.strip()
        g_line = g_line.strip()
        if not f_line or not g_line:
            continue
# 5
        cmd = "sed -i -e 's/%s/%s/g' %s" % \
                (f_line.strip(), g_line.strip(), tml_string)

        ret = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True).wait()
        if ret != 0:
            print "error doing string replacement"
            sys.exit(1)
```

You do not need to read in your entire files at once. If they are large this could be a lot of  memory. You can consume a line at a time, and you can also make use of what is called "context managers" when you open the files. This will ensure they close properly no matter what happens:

1. We start with a subprocess command that is run only once to find all your `.tml` files. Your version had the same command being run multiple times. If the search path is the same, then we only need it once. This checks the exit code of the command and quits if it failed.
2. We loop over `stdout` on the subprocess command, and add the stripped lines to a list. This is a more robust way of your `replace("\r\n")`. It removes whitespace. A "list comprehension" would be better suited here (down the line). If we didn't find any tml files, then we have no work to do, so we exit. Otherwise, we join them together in a space-separated string to be suitable for our command later.
3. This is called "context managers". You can open the file in a way that no matter what they will be closed properly. The file is open for the length of the context within that code block. We are going to loop forever, and break when appropriate.
4. We pull a line, one at a time, from each file. If either line is blank, we reached the end of the file and cannot do any more work, so we break out. We then strip the newlines, and if either string is empty (blank line) we still can't do any work, but we just continue to the next available line.
5. A modified version of your sed command. We construct the command string on each loop for the source and replacement strings, and tack on the tml file string. Bear in mind this is a very naive approach to the replacement. It really expects your replacement strings to be safe characters and not break the `s///g` sed format. But we run that with another `subprocess` command. The `wait()` simply waits for the return code, and we check it for an error. This approach replaces your `os.system()` version.

Hope this helps. Eventually you can improve this to do more checking and safe operations.

Comment: yes i tried that and i changed args = "[find . -name *.tml]" in the code also.but now error seems to be " not able to read path "

Comment: what i intent to do is to read two files and store it.
then remove all new line character.
Then i want to search the content of file1 in particular directoy (which has files and sub directories) and replace it with the corresponding content of file2.
Can you suggest me any other solution for this?

Comment: its showing syntax error at " open "
can you please check once?

Comment: You tried what? I completely rewrote your code. This code works perfectly fine for me and does exactly what you explained you wanted. It opens and reads the two files. Then it searches the current directory for all tml files, and performs the sed operation on them. Please post your exact error in a pastebin.com

Comment: Why would I go through all the trouble of suggesting a second solution to your problem when I have already given you a working first solution. You will need to specifically point out the spot that is not working properly for you.

Comment: import subprocess
import sys
import os
f=open("GUI_ML_StringIds_ORIG.txt")
g=open("GUI_ML_StringIds_new.txt")

f_line = f.readlines()
g_line = g.readlines()
i = 0
for line in f_line:
 if line.replace("\r\n", "") != g_line[i].replace("\r\n", "") :
  print (line)
  print(g_line[i])
  cmd = "sed -i 's/" + line.replace("\r\n", "") + "/" + g_line[i].replace("\r\n", "") +"/g' " + "`grep -l -R " + line.replace("\r\n", "") + " *.xml`"
  print(cmd)
  os.system(cmd)
 i = i + 1

Comment: The problem i m facing here isthe code reaches at sed it shows all the files to as input for sed command in print statement but 
but in cygwin window it says " no input files to sed "

Comment: Did you actually try my solution including my sed syntax?